# Database Normalization - Field depending on another non-key field

Tags: sql-server, database-normalization

The following is part of a table definition in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE User     
[UserId] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
[EatsFruit] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
[FavoriteFruit] NVARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
```

As you can imagine, UserId is the primary key. I used a simpler example here to explain my question related to the "fruit" fields.

The field EatsFruit will be either 1 or 0, depending on whether the user eats fruit or not. If EatsFruit contains a 1, then the FavoriteFruit field will include the user's favorite fruit. If EatsFruit is 0, then FavoriteFruit is not relevant and it would have to contain N/A or some similar value.

I am wondering what the best way to model this is, and whether it needs to be normalized.

Since the FavoriteFruit field depends on the content of EatsFruit, should it be separated in a different table containing UserId and FavoriteFruit? This would be cleaner, because an entry for a certain user would not appear unless the user actually eats fruits (and the content of FavoriteFruit would always be relevant). However, since the primary key of the new table would also be UserId, doesn't this mean that FavoriteFruit really depends on the UserId and should not have been separated from the main table in the first place?

What would be best practices here? Thank you so much!

Comment: It does not make sense to move it to another table. As you have stated, the relationship is 1:1. And unless you can have more than 1 favorite fruit it is simply a property of the User. I would perhaps suggest that you don't need nvarchar for fruit names unless they are going to be entered in chinese or some other language. It also might be a good idea to normalize your fruit to another table to avoid repetition.

Comment: @SeanLange I didnt saw the 1:1 part. But do the size matching the field matter? Like in my employee case?

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you, Sean. In that case, you don't think it would be bad design to have NULL values for FavoriteFruit everytime EatsFruit is 0?

Comment: I don't think it would be incorrect based on the example you provided. Especially if the column is a variable length it isn't going to eat up any disc space either.

Comment: @Irina I will agree with Sean, you can do it my way if want be super normailize and need to save the most bits you can. But you probably dont need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a pure normalization perspective, you don't want to have a field that is potentially taking up space with useless information, as you would in your example when the user doesn't eat fruit. Furthermore, you really don't want Favorite Fruit to be an NVarchar as "Melon" and "Watermelon" are different things (or are they), Or what about an entry of "Aple" on accident.

Were it me, I would have a Fruit Table and a FavoriteFruit Association table, The FavoriteFruit table would have the fruit id and the user id. If the user didn't have a favorite fruit, no space is used. Also, I would ask whether I could get rid of "EatsFruit" and simply check for an entry in the FavoriteFruits table.

That said, the way you have is set up, though maybe playing a little loose, is not an unpardonable sin.

Cheers.

Comment: You have text book normalization, then everything else.  Depends on how your using the data.

Answer (score 0):

The moment you start saving conditionals `NULL` in your table you know that data need to be normalized.

Imagine you have a field `anual_bonus` in your Employee table but only  managers get a bonus. You will have a lot of nulls in that field what will be a waste.

For this case I would have

User:

```
  user_id
```

EatFruit:

```
  user_id
  favorite_fruit_id (can be null if user eat fruit but doesnt have favorite?)
```

Fruits

```
  fruit_id
  fruit_name
```

so to get user who like fruits you do

```
SELECT user.*
FROM user
LEFT JOIN EatFruit
      on user.user_id = EatFruit.user_id
WHERE EatFruit.user_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Technically speaking wouldn't the annual bonus be treated as 0 when an employee does not receive a bonus? A NULL in this case is not actually a valid response because we DO know the value, and that value is 0. NULL indicates that the bonus amount is unknown which is incorrect in your example.

Comment: A many-to-may like this makes the most sense *if* having multiple users liking the same fruit makes sense, especially if you need to control spelling or available choices.  If the fruit were, say, a numeric value or a date, then a simple one-to-many with two tables might be preferable.

Comment: @SeanLange That rather depends on business rules.  A NULL bonus might mean the employee is ineligible for a bonus, while a bonus of 0 might indicate that a bonus was available but the value was reduced to 0 for some reason.

Comment: @BaconBits I would argue that NULL for a bonus value means they are ineligible is a valid business rule. If there is a reason to receive or not receive a bonus that is a property on its own. Having NULL for the bonus amount means that the bonus amount is not known or not provided. It should NOT be an indication of eligibility status.

Comment: @SeanLange What *anything* means when it is in the database is up to the business rules. In particular, the ones that say what a row means when it's in a particular table (its *predicate*).